# Why can't I reinterpret_cast uint to int?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, reinterpret-cast

Here's what I want to do:

`const int64_t randomIntNumber = reinterpret_cast<int64_t> (randomUintNumber);`

Where randomUintNumber is of type `uint64_t`.

The error is (MSVC 2010):

> error C2440: 'reinterpret_cast' : cannot convert from 'const uint64_t'
>   to 'int64_t' 1>          Conversion is a valid standard conversion,
>   which can be performed implicitly or by use of static_cast, C-style
>   cast or function-style cast

Why doesn't it compile? both types have the same bit length, isn't it what reinterpret_cast is intended for?

Comment: If you could list the errors you get, we might more easily say _why_ it doesn't compile.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: my bad, expanded the question.

Comment: Old post i know, C++20's std::bit_cast from the <bit> header does exactly this :>

Comment: @AnthoFoxo: Thanks! I use my own `memory_cast<>` a lot which uses `memcpy` to properly create a new object with the bit representation of the specified data, and I completely forgot `bit_cast` exists.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Because that's not what `reinterpret_cast` is for. All the permitted conversions with `reinterpret_cast` involve pointers or references, with the exception that an integer or enum type can be `reinterpret_cast` to itself. This is all defined in the standard, `[expr.reinterpret.cast]`.

I'm not certain what you're trying to achieve here, but if you want `randomIntNumber` to have the same value as `randomUintNumber`, then do

```
const int64_t randomIntNumber = randomUintNumber;
```

If that results in a compiler warning, or if you just want to be more explicit, then:

```
const int64_t randomIntNumber = static_cast<int64_t>(randomUintNumber);
```

The result of the cast has the same value as the input if `randomUintNumber` is less than 2<sup>63</sup>. Otherwise the result is implementation-defined, but I expect all known implementations that have `int64_t` will define it to do the obvious thing: the result is equivalent to the input modulo 2<sup>64</sup>.

---

If you want `randomIntNumber` to have the same bit-pattern as `randomUintNumber`, then you can do this:

```
int64_t tmp;
std::memcpy(&tmp, &randomUintNumber, sizeof(tmp));
const int64_t randomIntNumber = tmp;
```

Since `int64_t` is guaranteed to use two's complement representation, you would *hope* that the implementation defines `static_cast` to have the same result as this for out-of-range values of `uint64_t`. But it's not actually guaranteed in the standard AFAIK.

Even if `randomUintNumber` is a compile-time constant, unfortunately here `randomIntNumber` is *not* a compile-time constant. But then, how "random" is a compile-time constant? ;-)

If you need to work around that, and you don't trust the implementation to be sensible about converting out-of-range unsigned values to signed types, then something like this:

```
const int64_t randomIntNumber = 
    randomUintNumber <= INT64_MAX ? 
        (int64_t) randomUintNumber :
        (int64_t) (randomUintNumber - INT64_MAX - 1) + INT64_MIN;
```

Now, I'm in favour of writing truly portable code where possible, but even so I think this verges on paranoia.

---

Btw, you might be tempted to write this:

```
const int64_t randomIntNumber = reinterpret_cast<int64_t&>(randomUintNumber);
```

or equivalently:

```
const int64_t randomIntNumber = *reinterpret_cast<int64_t*>(&randomUintNumber);
```

This isn't quite guaranteed to work, because although where they exist `int64_t` and `uint64_t` are guaranteed to be a signed type and an unsigned type of the same size, they aren't actually guaranteed to be the signed and unsigned versions of a standard integer type. So it is implementation-specific whether or not this code violates strict aliasing. Code that violates strict aliasing has undefined behavior. The following does *not* violate strict aliasing, and is OK provided that the bit pattern in `randomUintNumber` is a valid representation of a value of `long long`:

```
unsigned long long x = 0;
const long long y = reinterpret_cast<long long &>(x);
```

So on implementations where `int64_t` and `uint64_t` are typedefs for `long long` and `unsigned long long`, then my `reinterpret_cast` is OK. And as with the implementation-defined conversion of out-of-range values to signed types, you would *expect* that the sensible thing for implementations to do is to make them corresponding signed/unsigned types. So like the `static_cast` and the implicit conversion, you expect it to work in any sensible implementation but it is not actually guaranteed.

Comment: (nitpicking) AFAIK, the guarantee that int64_t use two's complement representation is for C++20 and above

Comment: @Zejj: it's a long time ago now, but I thought `int64_t` has always been required to be 2's complement. If an implementation had a 64-bit signed integer type that wasn't 2's complement, maybe `long long` or something, then it was not permitted just to use that as `int64_t`. The `(u)intX_t` types also were required to have no padding bits and maybe some other constraints. But I'm just doing this from memory, and I'm uncertain whether there were differences between C and C++.

Comment: I also can't remember whether `int64_t` and `uint64_t` are actually required to have the same endian-ness, or not! Obviously it would be weird for them not to.

Comment: be explicit and use `auto`.

Answer (score 7):

Use `static_cast` in these cases.  I suppose the language designers in all their wisdom decided that it's not considered "unsafe enough" to warrant a `reinterpret_cast`.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not. `reinterpret_cast` is mostly intended to reinterpret an existing bit of storage as a different type than it is. A lot of these interpretations is implementation dependent, and the standard lists a specific (rather long to quote here) list of things that can be done with a `reinterpret_cast` (mostly casting between different pointer/reference types), but says:

> No other conversion can be performed explicitly using
>   reinterpret_cast.

In your case, you probably want a conversion of types, not a reinterpretation of existing storage. Use `static_cast` for this purpose.

Comment: But reinterpretation is exactly what I want! I'm not sure static_cast (or C-cast) will produce the desired result, have to refresh my memory on how it works first.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: If you want to reinterpret a certain storage as a different type, then you should reinterpret cast a pointer to that storage. Be aware though that you are entering IB/UB land here, especially if you are dereferencing the result.

Comment: How could I forget... That's exactly how I've solved this problem the last time I've encountered it (casting a pointer to target type and dereferencing it). Where exactly does IB/UB emerge here?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: the potential UB is due to strict aliasing, see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

## Reinterpret bit pattern with `memcpy`, transform type with `static cast`

Using `reinterpret_cast` you are violating `strict aliasing`.
This is bad, as it ends up with undefined behavior (maybe you code malfunctions with a new compiler version.)
[What is the Strict Aliasing Rule and Why do we care?](https://gist.github.com/shafik/848ae25ee209f698763cffee272a58f8) is a great article, describing the problem and its solution (maybe skip the lengthy part "Now, to the Rule-Book" ;) ). It recommends `memcpy` and argues, that compiler optimization will skip the copying anyway.

**code**

Interactive code [here](https://techiedelight.com/compiler/?YKG2). In your specific case, all options yield the same result. This changes, when playing with `newType` and `randomUintNumber`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    typedef int64_t newType; // try: double, int64_t
    
    uint64_t randomUintNumber = INT64_MAX + 10000; // try: 64000, INT64_MIN, INT64_MAX, UINT64_MAX, INT64_MAX + 10000
    std::cout << "INT64_MIN: " << INT64_MIN << std::endl;
    std::cout << "UINT64_MAX: " << UINT64_MAX << std::endl;
    std::cout << "INT64_MAX: " << INT64_MAX << "\n\n";
    std::cout << "randomUintNumber: " << randomUintNumber << "\n\n";
    
    // const int64_t randomIntNumber = reinterpret_cast<int64_t> (randomUintNumber);
    std::cout << "as \"const int64_t randomIntNumber = reinterpret_cast<int64_t> (randomUintNumber);\" does not work, here are some options ...\n\n";
    
    std::cout << "BAD [undefined behavior!]:" << std::endl;
    const newType a = reinterpret_cast<int64_t&> (randomUintNumber);
    std::cout << "\treinterpret_cast<int64_t&> (randomUintNumber): " << a << std::endl;
    
    const newType b = reinterpret_cast<int64_t&&> (randomUintNumber);
    std::cout << "\treinterpret_cast<int64_t&&> (randomUintNumber): " << b << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << "\nGOOD: " << std::endl;
    const newType c = (int64_t) randomUintNumber;
    std::cout << "\t(int64_t) randomUintNumber [static cast, sometimes reinterprets bit pattern]: " << c << std::endl;
    
    const newType d = static_cast<int64_t>(randomUintNumber);
    std::cout << "\tstatic_cast<int64_t>(randomUintNumber) [the same as before]: " << d << std::endl;
    
    static_assert(sizeof(uint64_t) == sizeof(newType), "should not be taken for granted ...");
    newType eNotConst;
    std::memcpy(&eNotConst, &randomUintNumber, sizeof(uint64_t));
    const newType e = eNotConst;
    std::cout << "\tstd::memcpy(&eNotConst, &randomUintNumber, sizeof(uint64_t)); [definately reinterprets bit pattern]: " << e << std::endl;
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

**output**

```
INT64_MIN: -9223372036854775808
UINT64_MAX: 18446744073709551615
INT64_MAX: 9223372036854775807

randomUintNumber: 9223372036854785807

as "const int64_t randomIntNumber = reinterpret_cast<int64_t> (randomUintNumber);" does not work, here are some options ...

BAD [undefined behavior!]:
    reinterpret_cast<int64_t&> (randomUintNumber): -9223372036854765809
    reinterpret_cast<int64_t&&> (randomUintNumber): -9223372036854765809

GOOD: 
    (int64_t) randomUintNumber [static cast, sometimes reinterprets bit pattern]: -9223372036854765809
    static_cast<int64_t>(randomUintNumber) [the same as before]: -9223372036854765809
    std::memcpy(&eNotConst, &randomUintNumber, sizeof(uint64_t)); [definately reinterprets bit pattern]: -9223372036854765809
```

Answer (score 2):

From C++11 Standard(N3376) 5.2.10.1 [this document, page 101](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3376.pdf):

> Conversions that can be performed explicitly using reinterpret_cast are listed below. No
> other conversion can be performed explicitly using reinterpret_cast.

The only conversion from integral type to integral type allowed is infact if the types are identical.

Others involve pointers.

Answer (score 1):

> Why doesn't it compile?

Because neither type is a pointer.

> both types have the same bit length,

Why would that matter? If they were pointers, maybe it would matter that they pointed to things of the same size, but they're not pointers.

> isn't it what reinterpret_cast is intended for?

No, `reinterpret_cast` is for pointer casts. You could do what you want by putting an `&` inside the cast and a `*` outside it. That's what reinterpret cast is for.

Comment: Bit length matters because you'd have problems bitwise reinterpreting types of different length, obviously.

Comment: This is a common misunderstanding about `reinterpret_cast`. It doesn't, conceptually, do a bitwise reinterpretation (though on common platforms it 'happens to'). For example, the C++ standard (5.2.10) says that with reinterpret_cast, a "pointer can be explicitly converted to any integral type large enough to hold it." -- that includes *larger* integral types. And, it explicitly says it "might, or might not, produce a representation different from the original value".

Comment: @VioletGiraffe When using the results of a `reinterpret_cast`, the bit length of the pointed to (or refered to) objects matters.  The bit lengths of the pointers themselves is irrelevant: you can `reinterpret_cast` between `char*` and `int*`, even when `char*` and `int*` have different sizes (as they sometimes did on older machines).

Answer (score 1):

`reinterpret_cast` is used for reinterpreting the storage of the object as a different object. If you don't want to go through standard wording, you can find all that `reinterpret_cast` can do [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast). Generally you can remember you have to work with pointer types.

So, if you really want to reinterpret the bits used for your `uint64_t` as `int64_t`, then do this:

```
int64_t randomIntNumber = reinterpret_cast<int64_t&> (randomUintNumber);
```

However if you just want to convert the object, preserving its value if possible ... just do what the compiler suggests and use `static_cast` instead.