# reinterpret_cast - bizarre behaviour

Tags: c++, casting, constants, reinterpret-cast

I've come across bizarre error related to reinterpret_cast. Just look at below code:

```
int* var;
reinterpret_cast<void const **>(&var);
```

error in VSC++2010: error C2440: 'reinterpret_cast' : cannot convert from 'int ** ' to 'const void ** '

error in gcc 4.1.2: reinterpret_cast from type ‘int** ’ to type ‘const void** ’ casts away constness

error in gcc 4.6.2: reinterpret_cast from type ‘int** ’ to type ‘const void** ’ casts away qualifiers

Does anyone have a clue why compilers say that I'm casting const away. Me, and few of my work colleagues have no idea what's wrong with it.

Thanks for help!

Comment: The "casts away qualifiers" is confusing.  I think a better error message would say "changes qualifiers".

Comment: Confusing and inappropriate error message is one thing, but I have no clue why compiler thinks, that this is wrong.

Comment: Also see answers to 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14623266/why-cant-i-reinterpret-cast-uint-to-int/14623381#14623381

Comment: Also see answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016098/implicit-cast-from-char-to-const-char

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Section 5.2.10 of the C++03 standard talks about what a reinterpret_cast can do.  It explicitly states "The reinterpret_cast operator shall not cast away constness".

Casting away constness is defined in section 5.2.11 of the C++03 standard.  The notation used there is a little confusing, but it basically states that casting between two types "casts away constness" if there is no implicit conversion for the given qualification.

In your case, you are trying to convert an `int **` to a `void const**`.  The compiler asks "Can I implicitly convert between `T **` and `T const**`?", and the answer is no, so it says that you are casting away constness.

The logic here is that reinterpret_cast is made to handle changing types, not changing qualifiers (that's what const_cast is for).  So if you are asking it to do something you would need const_cast for, it refuses.

Comment: Great answer! That explained all. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To add/remove `const`, use `const_cast`.

To deal with confusing casting errors, do things one step at a time:

```
int* var;
int** v2 = &var;
int const** v3 = const_cast<int const**>(v2);
void const** v4 = reinterpret_cast<void const**>(v3);
```

Note that a `int const**` and a `int**` are very different types, and converting between them is dangerous -- more dangerous than a `void*` <-> `int*`.

Suppose you have an `int** bob`.  You then pass it to a function that takes a `int const** alice` through a `const_cast`.

In that function, they assign a pointer to an int stored in read-only memory to the `*alice` -- perfectly legal.

Outside the function, you check that `bob` and `*bob` are valid, then assign to `**bob`, and you just tried to write to read-only memory.